# Mudar data que aparece em um datepicker

Tags: javascript, html5

Possuo o seguinte datepicker:

```
var dataIni = document.querySelector("#calendarioIni");
var dataFim = document.querySelector("#calendarioFim");

function checaVazio(){
  var botao = document.querySelector("form input[type='submit']");
  botao.style.display = dataIni.value && dataFim.value ? "inline" : "none";
}

var start = new Date(1998, 00, 01);
var end = new Date(1998, 11, 31) ;

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        startDate: '01/01/1998', // 1 de Janeiro de 1998
        endDate: '31/12/1998', // 31 de Janeiro de 1998,
        defaultViewDate: { year: 1998, month: 0, day: 1 },
        onSelect: checaVazio
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#calendarioFim').datepicker({
        defaultViewDate: new Date(1998, 0, 1),
        endDate: end,
        startDate: start,
        onSelect: checaVazio
    });
});
```

Gostaria de mudar o mês que aparece quando abro o calendário (atualmente quando clico abre em Dezembro, queria mudar para janeiro), tentei fazer isso com o "startView" mas não funcionou. Assim que utilizo ele:

```
<form method="post" action="">
      Início do período:
      <input type="text" id="calendarioIni" name="dataInicio">
      Fim do período:
      <input type="text" id="calendarioFim" name="dataFim"> 
      <input style="display: none;" type="submit" value="Consultar" />                                    
      <br><br><br>

      <?php if(isset($_POST['dataInicio']) && isset($_POST['dataFim']))
      {
            $dataIni = $_POST['dataInicio'];
            $dataFim = $_POST['dataFim'];
            echo $dataIni."<br>";//Teste para verificar o valor nas variáveis que recebem a data via POST
            echo $dataFim."<br>";
            } 
     ?>                                    
</form>
```

Comment: Complemente sua pergunta explicando qual componente datepicker você está utilizando. Se puder, crie um código executável no jsfiddle.net.

Comment: o que vc quis dizer com componente? Se é bootstrap?

Comment: componente mesmo porque o datepicker não é algo nativo do Javascript. Por exemplo, pode ser o DatePicker do JQuery UI ou pode ser outro.

Comment: então, utilizo o bootstrap e o jquery, basicamente chamo ele assim    
 <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js'></script>

Comment: Não precisaria ter `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` duas vezes. Você pode fazer tudo dentro de um bloco só. E o `defaultViewDate` do `#calendarioFim` está incorreto. Tem que usar o formato igual o do `#calendarioIni`, ou seja, passar um objeto com os atributos `year`, `month` e `day`.

Comment: eu tbm uso pra um DataTable, poderia colocar junto também?

Comment: Pode sim. Se compartilham do mesmo evento, pode colocar.

Comment: entendi, mas eles não compartilham o mesmo evento

Comment: só não consigo entender o seguinte: fui na classe do datepicker e fiz algumas modificações, por exemplo, mudei a linguagem, porém não aplica essa modificação... o comportamento tá meio aleatório, tem mudanças que faço que altera e outras não

Comment: Se todos os três estão dentro do escopo de um `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`, então compartilham do mesmo evento que é quando o *DOM* está totalmente carregado. Aí você pode unir em um só.

Comment: mas não compartilham... o primeiro gera uma tabela para gerar um pdf e o segundo é para exibir o calendario e o usuário selecionar as datas

Comment: Se você referencia o seu datepicker dessa forma (apontando para um arquivo na pasta JS local) não tem como saber qual componente é. Existem dezenas de componentes datepicker que usam bootstrap por isso é interessante você indicar de qual site você baixou porque cada um tem configuração e comportamento diferente.

Comment: @Pagotti pior que não tem como eu saber de onde foi baixado, pois "herdei" esse projeto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Classe Date**

A classe `Date` do *JavaScript* aceita diversos parâmetros que serão utilizados em seu construtor. Um dos problemas é que o parâmetro referente aos meses utiliza um intervalo de `0-11`, sendo `0` Janeiro e `11` o mês de Dezembro.

Então, quando você inicia dessa maneira: `var start = new Date(1997, 12, 01);` vai gerar uma data não esperada e usando o `console.log(start);` vai resultar em: `1998-01-01T02:00:00.000Z`, ou seja, `01/01/1998` e não `01/12/1997`.

Você pode instanciar o objeto da classe `Date` de diversas maneiras, por exemplo:

```
let data = new Date('January 1, 2018'); // 1 de Janeiro de 2018
```

Ou:

```
let data = new Date('2018-01-01'); // 1 de Janeiro de 2018
```

Leia mais sobre a classe `Date` no **w3schools**: [JavaScript Dates](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

---

**Datepicker**

Já no *Datepicker*, a opção correta para definir a data de início é a `defaultDate`.

Leia mais sobre o plugin *Datepicker* do *jQuery*: [Datepicker Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

---

### EDIT:

Tente fazer dessa forma:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#calendarioIni').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '01/01/1998', // 1 de Janeiro de 1998
    endDate: '31/12/1998', // 31 de Dezembro de 1998,
    defaultViewDate: { year: 1998, month: 0, day: 1 } // Coloca o foco em 1 de Janeiro de 1998
  });
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<form>
  Início do período:
  <input type="text" name="dataInicio" id="calendarioIni">
</form>
```

Comment: acrescentei aqui o dafaultDate e não funcionou... o jquery eu já chamo através do footer da seguinte maneira:  
<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script> e dou um include("footer.php"); na página

Comment: O código postado aqui funciona. Edite sua pergunta com o código atualizado, por favor.

Comment: a única coisa que eu fiz foi acrescentar o defaultDate e o código não funcionou... acredito que o problema pode ser algo em relação ao jquery

Comment: Tire o `startDate` e o `endDate` e teste novamente. Editei minha resposta com a data que você colocou e funciona normalmente.

Comment: retirei, e a data que aparece é o mês atual

Comment: quando eu chamo o jquery da forma que vc fez nem aparece o calendario

Comment: Qual plugin do *Datepicker* está usando? O que usei é o oficial do *jQuery*.

Comment: onde eu poderia ver isso? o cabeçalho do meu jquery tem isso:    /*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v3.1.0
 * https://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * https://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2016-07-07T21:44Z
 */

Comment: Esse é o *jQuery*. Você precisa ver se tem algum outro *script* sendo incluído no seu código, por exemplo: `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/datepicker.js"></script>`

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js'></script>

Comment: poderíamos ir para o chat?

Comment: Editei a resposta pra esse plugin que você está utilizando. Por favor, dá uma olhada.

Comment: mas o usuário poderá selecionar qualquer dia do ano, dessa forma ele fica limitado a janeiro

Comment: É só um exemplo. Você pode ajustar os intervalos do `startDate` e `endDate` conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: ah sim, mas é que eu gostaria que aparecesse em janeiro e não em dezembro

Comment: Editei novamente, dá uma olhada e veja se é assim que você precisa.

Comment: tem algo de muito estranho no meu código, não funcionou isso, o "defaultViewDate" nem chegou a ficar destacado na minha IDE

Comment: Posta seu código novamente, por favor.

Comment: vou editar o post com ele completo